# MVC6 / ASP.net ViewModel issue (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm super super tired right now and probably have done a big rookie mistake. 
I'm doing a ViewModel to grab all my models in 1 main model class. So far I've only done News and already hitting in a error..

See error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>   AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml+d__21.MoveNext() in
>   Index.cshtml
>   +
>       @foreach(News news in Model.Newss)

(Yes my naming is messed up but wanted to see foundation worked first).

Anyways: 
News.cs :

```
namespace UKSF.Models
{
    public class News
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainViewModels.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace UKSF.Models
    {
        public class MainViewModel
        {
            public List<News> Newss { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

index.cshtml:

```
@model UKSF.Models.MainViewModel 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

    @foreach(News news in Model.Newss)
    {
        @news.Title
    }
```

**EDIT:**
As you guys pointed out, the error was due of me not initializing it, I believed I had already done that in Controller page. 
Now its:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel();
    model.Newss = new List<News>();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Are you initializing the `Newss` property to a list before using it ? If not it will be `NULL`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you ever initializing your `Newss` collection prior to using it? If not, it will be null and will throw a `NullReferenceException` when you attempt to iterate through it in your foreach loop.

Consider initializing it in a constructor:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
        public List<News> Newss { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
             // This will initialize the collection when a new instance of
             // your model is created
             Newss = new List<News>();
        }
}
```

or inline using an auto-property initializer:

```
// This will set the default value to a new list instead of null
public List<News> Newss { get; set; } = new List<News>();
```

Comment: Thank you +1 
That was the correct solution, I thought I had done it. Now I just have to retrieve context and happy days! Thank you once again!!

Comment: Just a question.. ApplicationDbContext, what is the best way to utilize it to retrieve i.e "title" rows from News model?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your list

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UKSF.Models
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
           Newss = new List<News>();
        }
        public List<News> Newss { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized your list. Create a constructor and initialize it there.

```
Newss = new List<News>();
```

EDIT: Or you can do it in-line like Rion's answer.